# Android Virtual Device error: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: android, capacitor

I am simply trying to make a **Capacitor** (Angular) HTTP GET Request from the Android Virtual Device (API 29) to an API (.NET 6.0) also running on my PC.

In production I would change the API to only use HTTPS but for development I wanted HTTP as I wouldn't expect the AVD to accept the self-signed certificate.

The error I see is simply

```
 was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://10.0.2.2:5409/FromMobile/test'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I assume this is an issue mainly because Capacitor is serving via HTTPS but the call is to a non-secured HTTP api.

I tried with my IP address too but had the same error.

I have already added

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to the manifest.xml file.

I also tried adding the network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

But no change

**UPDATE:**
I have also tried installing the certificate on to the phone but this had made no difference

Comment: I'd try creating an emulator with Android 6 (API 23) and see if the same result occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the [Capacitor config](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config):

```js
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'http',
    cleartext: true
  },
  android: {
    allowMixedContent: true
  },
};
```

Comment: Unfortuantely this results in an error E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://main.107ce85403339656.js - Line 1 - Msg: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'digest' of undefined

Comment: @MadEddie, have you tried to remove `androidScheme` from config?

Comment: This worked for me @plplmax, thank you! I had to remove the androidScheme.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Thanks - Tried this but it seems to stop other valid SSL endpoints working

Comment: In general, this command doesn't cause any problem for SSL endpoints, also you can remove it for real test for SSL endpoints.